# How to assign groups based on a column value

Tags: r, dplyr, statistics, data.table, aggregate

I have the following df:

```r
Marker CHR      val  Position
1        1      2.10     1
2        1      2.11     10
3        1      3.33     20
4        1      3.55     30
5        1      2.06     40
6        2      2.03     1
7        2      3.04     10
8        2      3.10     20
9        2      3.05     30
10       2      2.90     40
```

How can I assign groups based on val value (for example val > 3) using a windows size based on the column position.

Comment: What is the expected output

Answer (score 1):

What is the expected output? Maybe something like this?

```
library(tidyverse)

test <- read_csv('sample.csv')

test %>% mutate(group = case_when(val >= 20 & val <= 49 ~ 'Group 1',
                                      val >= 50 & val <= 69 ~ 'Group 2',
                                      val >= 70 & val <= 100 ~ 'Group 3')) %>%
                                      group_by(group) 

# A tibble: 9 x 5
# Groups:   group [3]
Marker   CHR   val Position group  
<dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>  
1      1     1    20        5 Group 1
2      2     1    30        6 Group 1
3      3     2    40        7 Group 1
4      4     2    50        8 Group 2
5      5     3    60        9 Group 2
6      6     4    70       10 Group 3
7      7     2    80       11 Group 3
8      8     1    90       12 Group 3
9      9     1   100       13 Group 3
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this also helps

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  mutate(group = cut(val, breaks = c(20, 50, 70, 100), 
      labels = c('Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3')))
```